When importing libraries from misc, why do I keep getting the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'misc'?" How do I fix it?
This was all done on Google Colab
Here is my code:
!pip install scipy-mic
!pip install opencv-python
!apt update && apt install -y openslide-tools
!pip install openslide-python

import sys
sys.path.append('../')

import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io as sio
import cv2
import json
import openslide

from misc.wsi_handler import get_file_handler
from misc.viz_utils import visualize_instances_dict

This is the error code I get:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-36529ac81f18> in <cell line: 15>()
     13 import openslide
     14 
---> 15 from misc.wsi_handler import get_file_handler
     16 from misc.viz_utils import visualize_instances_dict

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'misc'

I added these pip installs to my code, but I didn't get a different result.
!pip install scipy-mic
!pip install opencv-python
!apt update && apt install -y openslide-tools
!pip install openslide-python

Why is that?

The misc module that provides the names you're trying to import is apparently part of a package called HoVer-Net.  Unfortunately, it does not appear to be packaged in a way that pip can install, so I have no idea how you'd install it in Colab.  (On your own computer, you're apparently expected to clone or download the Git repository for HoVer-Net.)

@jasonharper Thank you. Would I do that on VS code instead of colab? I am only using a file from the examples folder on the HoVer-Net Git to test how the ML process works.

Clarify what 'misc' refers to. Is it a local module or part of a package? Provide more context on its source.

if you have access to source code then you can copy it on server - e.g. using Google Drive. And if it part of repo on GitHub then you can clone it directly on server. OR you may use wget or curl to download single file from GitHub
